# How to perform the indexing for xpath in cypress automation?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I want to make common function in cypress automation for that, I want to use the locators and xpath to find the element but I am facing issue using indexes in xpath cypress.

In selenium automation, it is easy to create parameterized xpath but in cypress facing issues?

Comment: please provide more details of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Suppose this is the common  xpath CLICK_ON_DONE_BUTTON = "(//button[contains(text(), 'Done')])[2] "; and in the last pass value [%s] as we do in the selenium can we do this in the cypress please let me know.......?

Comment: like pass 1, 2, 3 for indexing the button using one xpath ....

Comment: how can we make common xpath??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypress does not support xpath directly. You have to use the `xpath` plugin. See [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-xpath) for more details on how to add this plugin to your project.

After that, you will be able to call the `xpath` command.
For using indexes, you can write something like the following:

```js
      for (const i of [1,2,3]) {
        cy.xpath(`(//button[contains(text(), 'Done')])[${i}]`)
      }
```

If you need to parameterize your expression, you can define a function:

```js
      function containsAtIndex(i) {
        return cy.xpath(`(//button[contains(text(), 'Done')])[${i}]`)
      }
```

Or define a custom cypress command. With the [Cypress Support Pro](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13987-cypress-support-pro) plugin, it's easy and can be done in a couple of clicks:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I know about the xpath plugin. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: There is one more question, if we define our XPath at the top of the file with this "[${i}]" then how we will pass the value from the method to get the exact button.
Please let know, if any solution because I am following the POM design pattern for that I want to pass the index value from the method itself.

Comment: You can use either a function or a custom command. I updated the answer with

Answer (score 0):

You can use eq to specify the index.

In your example it will look like this:
cy.contains('button', 'Done').eq(2)